# django-multilingual and switching between languages on template side

Tags: python, django, django-i18n, django-multilingual, i18n-switcher

I'm trying to use django-multilingual and setup it properly. But what I found is that everything is clear for django-multilingual except a template usage example.

I just started to use django and I don't know, maybe because of this reason, I cannot figure out how to switch between languages on template side.

Is there any example that you can give or any 'more' clear source/documentation about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

switching locale in django is a simple post do this view

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view

in templates you can access the language value with request.LANGUAGE_CODE

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to try [django-localeurl](http://code.google.com/p/django-localeurl/) app. It enables users to switch locales storing current locale in the URL. It also provides several useful template tags for switching and displaying available locales.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **i18n switcher** following [The set_language redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) but first, you better set up translation(**English** and **French**) following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418) and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547342/how-to-create-i18n-switcher-for-django-admin) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547342/how-to-create-i18n-switcher-for-django-admin#answer-76547343) explaining how to create **i18n switcher** for Django Admin. *I use **Django 4.2.1**.

Then, add `path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n"))` to `urlpatterns` in `core/settings.py` as shown below. *You should not include `path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n"))` in `i18n_patterns()` to work correctly according to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view):

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("my_app1/", include('my_app1.urls')),
)

# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
urlpatterns += [
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n"))
]
```

Then, add `<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" ...>...</form>` to `templates/index.html` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/index.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
{% ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ %}

{% translate "Hello" %} {% trans "World" %}
```

Now, you can switch **English** to **French** as shown below:

[image]

And, you can switch **French** to **English** as shown below:

[image]