# Issue trying to change language from Django template

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I need to include two buttons or links to allow users change language between English and Spanish. I've read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) and tried this:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="language" type="hidden" value="es" />
    <input type="submit" value="ES" />
</form>
```

However, every time I click the button, the page is reloaded but the language doesn't change at all. Am I missing something?

Note: I haven't set `next`, as I just want to reload the current page in the desired language.

If I use the default form provided by the docs the result is the same: the page reloads but language isn't changed:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE**:

After further testing, I've noticed that there is a problem using both `i18n_patterns` and `patterns` in the `urls.py`. Currently I have a file that looks like:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^contents/', include('contents.urls')),
    url(r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
    # ...
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

And this doesn't seem to work. However, if I remove the `i18n_patterns` and change it to `patterns` then it seems to work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^contents/', include('contents.urls')),
    url(r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
    # ...
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

The docs say that you don't have to include it inside `i18n_patterns`, so I think this should work, but it doesn't! It doesn't matter if you include `django.conf.urls.i18n` before or after `i18n_patterns` it always does the same.

Comment: Perhaps try to see if django successfully set the language cookie, it defaults to a cookie named `django_language`, use your browser's dev tool to see what are the cookies before and after.

Comment: Hi @Ziyan! I've just posted the solution! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After more testing and thanks to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489601/django-i18n-change-language) linked by @AronYsidoro I've finally found the issue and a very simple solution that actually solves this.

First, let me explain the problem: When working with `i18_patterns` in your `urls.py` to prepend the language code, if you call the URL `set_language` to change the language without specifying `next`, it defaults to the current one, but with the prepended old language code! So, the language gets back to the original! And, if you explicitly specify `next`, you must be sure to do not include the language code at the begining.

If you use `{{ request.path }}` or `{{ request.get_full_path }}` to specify the `next` as the current page this won't work as it returns the language code too.

So, how do we remove this undesired language code to reload the current page with the language changed when using `i18n_patterns`? Easy, we just have to slice the 3 first chars (the slash and the two chars language code)!

Here you have two examples. The first one in form of a select (with the languages as choices) and the other one in form of a button (per language).

I really hope this helps someone else. You can just copy and paste the code and it should work. However, if using the "button form", you just have to set the language to your desired!

**Change language from list:**

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
  <select name="language">
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
      {% for language in languages %}
        <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
          {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
        </option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>
```

**Change language as button:**

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
  <input name="language" type="hidden" value="es" />
  <input type="submit" value="ES" />
</form>
```

**Edit:**
Some languages code are larger than 2 characters (like zh-hans, zh-hant), therefore, do something like:

```
{% if get_current_language == 'zh-hans' or get_current_language == 'zh-hant' %}
    <li><a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'8:' }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }}) <b>{% if language.code == get_current_language %} ✓ {% endif %}</b></a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }}) <b>{% if language.code == get_current_language %} ✓ {% endif %}</b></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that `{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}` will likely fail if `prefix_default_language=False`. It's probably best to place a check otherwise there's the risk of slicing a valid part of the url.

Comment: Apart from the comment above, most, but not all language codes have two letters, eg. de_DE, zh-Hans, so it’s dangerous to rely on that. `'/'.join(request.get_full_path.split('/')[1:])` in Python, e. g. template tag, would be better.

Comment: Note also that with this approach the sliced part will not be translated and will be returned as-is.

Comment: No, no! You want to change the language and reload the page? Simply set `<input name="next" type="hidden" value="">`  and you're fine. Django documentation lacks explaining `set_language` in detail.

Comment: Be aware that some languages code are larger than 2 characters (like zh-hans, zh-hant)

Answer (score 20):

A sum-up of possible options:

#### Change the user's session language with a `select`

There is an excellent extensive description with example on [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#miscellaneous).

#### Change the user's session language with buttons

There is no need to repeat a form for each button as @Caumons suggested, instead you can simply include as many buttons in the form as the languages.

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <li>
                <button type="submit"
                        name="language"
                        value="{{ language.code }}"
                        class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
                    {{ language.name_local }}
                </button>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

You can certainly style up the buttons to look like links or whatever.

#### Change the language displayed with links

If it is not required that the default user session language is changed, then simple links can be used to change the content:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {% for language in languages %}
        <li>
            <a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}"
               class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}"
               lang="{{ language.code }}">
                {{ language.name_local }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### SEO

I am not entirely sure that the content is seo friendly if a form is used to change the session language, as Django recommends. Therefore it is possible that the link `<a>` markup is added as hidden below the `<button>` element.

Answer (score 2):

If in your current system you have only 2 languages then simply use like below:

```
{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE "en" %}
       <a href="/es{{ request.get_full_path }}">Spanish</a>
{% else %}
       <a href="/en{{ request.get_full_path }}">English</a>
{% endifequal %}
```

No need of a form, url and submit etc. It worked for me.

Comment: `request.get_full_path` returns the language component too, so `|slice:'3:'` is necessary.

Comment: This is a bad answer and a bad approach, 1st You are harcoding URLs, 2nd this is not recommended in the documentation. 3rd get_full_path returns also the language code

Answer (score 2):

Besides adding form that was suggested here:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ request.get_full_path_info|slice:'3:'}}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ languageless_url }}" />
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {% for language in languages %}
    <li>
      <button type="submit" name="language" value="{{ language.code }}"
        class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
        {{ language.code }}
      </button>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</form>
```

I would suggest adding a context processor (app.context_processors.py):

```
def language_processor(request):
"""
This is needed for language picker to work
"""
return {
    'languageless_url':
    '/' + '/'.join(request.get_full_path().split('/')[2:])
}
```

This allows to leave the logic out of template.
Also don't forget to add your processor in template settings:

```
            'context_processors': [
            'app.context_processors.language_processor',
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need two languages, ex. English and French and you've defined this in your settings.py and you have set the default language and you have configured urls.py in your main app correctly. Then, just use this in your template (or partial, topbar etc.) `btn-kinito "btn-header` are just styling classes you can manipulate that with css or JS.

The loop or iteration inside is just looping through the `LANGUAGES[]` list, which you've defined in `settings.py`, then it creates a button. with the character "|" and a space `&nbsp;` to make it look cute since we have just two langs.

The `{% url 'set_language' %}` is Django's redirect view called set_language it redirects to URL. This is why in your main apps's urls.py you need to put `path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),` In this case. So after the button is created for each language in the list you will be able to be redirected to that url.

```
  <div class="btn-header">
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
          <button type="submit" name="language" value="{{ language.code }}"
            class="btn-kinito">
            {{ language.code }}
          </button>|&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
  </div>
```

For urls.py I think it could look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns


# I don't want my admin translated
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns (
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('cats', include('cats.urls')),
    path('dogs', include('dogs.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False,
 ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The `prefix_default_language=False,` this is optional and it removes the default language prefix from the url, which makes sense if you just got two or three languages. Although I did run into problems with this in the past, where the `prefix_default_language=False,` did not work.

**How to fix the problem with `prefix_default_language=False,` NOT working, or not removing the default language prefix from urls**

In my settings.py I changed: 
`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` to `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'`

(seems to have solved it)

Comment: Hello Elias @elias-glyptis, thank you for the great suggestions. I have followed them and things work nicely. One problem I have encountered is that when I select the language, the URL pattern looks correct, the page refreshes, but the webpage is still being presented in English. It is not picking up the translations I have made. Do you have any suggestions about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Michel @MichelMesquita, you're welcome :) I think perhaps you may have a problem with compiling your translations in your .po file. I answered this issue on a different question here is the link to that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937217/8149936 let me know if that answer resolves the issues of compilation. There is also another answer in regards to where your env folder is located, because this can cause issues too, here is another link to help you trouble shoot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937217/8149936

Comment: opps sorry, here is the second link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717573/8149936

Comment: Hi @elias-glyptis, the links you've sent me were very useful. Thanks a lot! Your detailed explanations helped go through my code thoroughly! Much appreciated! I have made a number of tests: locally and on Heroku. But the translations are still not taking effect. I was wondering if it has something to do with `gettext` on my Mac? I've installed it with `brew`. Here's the page I am building. The words "PL8 Shop", "Products", and "Your cart is empty" should be translated. Thanks! http://pl8.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a solid solution but I needed a switch button (not a dropdown list since I want to toggle between two languages)
So I came up with this:

```
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == languages.0.code %}
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="lang-btn">
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ languages.1.code }}" />
        <button type="submit"><img width="30" src="{% static 'united-kingdom.png' %}" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        </form>
{% else %}
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="lang-btn">
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
            <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ languages.0.code }}" />
            <button type="submit"><img width="30" src="{% static 'turkey.png' %}" alt=""></button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

 <div class="btn-header">
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        {% for language in languages %}
            {% if language.code != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                <button type="submit" name="language" value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name }}</button>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
  </div>
```

if you have two languages. It will only show you the one that's off.

https://www.loom.com/share/9319c0e9204f417a8eec897965ce3a96

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.02

```
<div class="uk-flex">

    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    <div class="languages">
        <p>{% trans "Language" %}:</p>
        <ul class="languages">
        {% for language in languages %}
            <li>
                <a href="/{{ language.code }}/{{ request.get_full_path |slice:'4:'}}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems lot of people have spend a lot of time (like myself) finding a proper solution that works for all cases. "Trick" is to set `next = ''` if you want to reload existing page in different language. Citing from the django doc:

> After setting the language choice, Django looks for a next parameter in the POST or GET data. If that is found and Django considers it to be a safe URL (i.e. it doesn’t point to a different host and uses a safe scheme), a redirect to that URL will be performed. Otherwise, Django may fall back to redirecting the user to the URL from the Referer header

Finally I wanted to have a **function** that I can call for any language changes **triggered by links, buttons, dropdown menus or whatever**. I ended up with this little js function:

```
django_language_set(language_code){
  url = "{% url 'set_language' %}";
  data = {
    language: language_code,
    next: '',
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
  };
  this.form_post(url, data)
}

form_post(path, params, method='post') {
  /* simulates a post submit, call like:
    form_post('/home', {language: 'de', next: ''})"
  */
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.method = method;
  form.action = path;

  for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
      hiddenField.name = key;
      hiddenField.value = params[key];

      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Call the function, e.g.

```
<a @click="django_language_set('fr')">French</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a solution with buttons and the flags icon:

```
 <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ languageless_url }}" />
    <a class="btn  dropdown-sm-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="/static/img/flags/{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}.svg" width="20" height="30"></a>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" id="language-list">
      {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
      {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
      {% for language in languages %}
      <li>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="language" value="{{ language.code }}"
          class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
          <img src="/static/img/flags/{{ language.code }}.svg" width="20" height="30">&nbsp;&nbsp;
          {#{{ language.code }}#}{{ language.name_local }}
        </button>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </form>
```