# Switch language in Django with the translated url redirect

Tags: django, url, internationalization

I have internationalization correctly installed.

It's works with urls like:

```
/en/bookings/ #English
/es/reservas/ #Spanish
```

In the home page the language switching works fine too.

**- What's the issue?**

**When I change the language in a translated page, like /en/bookings/, if I turn the language to Spanish (es) I am redirected to /en/bookings/ again and I see the page in English.**

If I change the prefix ([like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392405/issue-trying-to-change-language-from-django-template/18393243#18393243)) the redirection goes to /es/bookings/ that doesn't exists.

I don't want to be redirected to the home page.

**- What I like?**

**If I am in the /en/bookings/ and switch to Spanish I want to be redirected to /es/reservas/, for all the translated urls.**

What is the best way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem so I sending my resolution to save Your time.

main(urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')), 
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('index.urls', namespace='index')),
)
```

(index.urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index/index.html'), name='index'),
    url(_(r'^python-programming/$'), TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index/new_page.html'),
        name='new_page'),
]
```

Creating template tag to return urls for current location in all languages that we support (index.templatetags.helper_tags.py)

```
from django.template import Library
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, reverse
from django.utils.translation import activate, get_language

register = Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def change_lang(context, lang=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Get active page's url by a specified language
    Usage: {% change_lang 'en' %}
    """

    path = context['request'].path
    url_parts = resolve(path)

    url = path
    cur_language = get_language()
    try:
        activate(lang)
        url = reverse(url_parts.view_name, kwargs=url_parts.kwargs)
    finally:
        activate(cur_language)

    return "%s" % url
```

Creating middleware to change site language when user will click at alternative link to this sub site but in different language
(middleware.py)

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class LangBasedOnUrlMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request):

        if hasattr(request, 'session'):
            active_session_lang = request.session.get(translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)

            if active_session_lang == request.LANGUAGE_CODE:
                return

            if any(request.LANGUAGE_CODE in language for language in settings.LANGUAGES):
                translation.activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
                request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
```

Adding it to (settings.py) just after LocaleMiddleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'our_app.middleware.LangBasedOnUrlMiddleware',
]
```

Sample usage in template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load helper_tags %}
    {% get_available_languages as languages %}
    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
        <a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% change_lang lang_code %}">
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Awesome job. Beautiful code. Thank you so much. btw this answer must be confirm.

Answer (score 2):

When I had the same problem, I implemented a custom template tag (current_url) that, given the request in context, re-renders the url for the active language:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<ul>
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
    {# IMPORTANT! enclose the 'current_url' tag in a 'language' block #}
    {% language language.code %}
        <li {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}class="active"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% current_url %}">{{ language.name_local }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endlanguage %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is the code for the custom tag (custom_tags.py):

```
import six
import sys
from django.template import Node, TemplateSyntaxError, Library
from django.conf import settings

register = Library()

class CurrentURLNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, asvar=None):
        self.asvar = asvar

    def render(self, context):
        request = context['request']
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch
        url = ''
        try:
            url = reverse(request.resolver_match.view_name, args=request.resolver_match.args, kwargs=request.resolver_match.kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
        except NoReverseMatch:
            exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            if settings.SETTINGS_MODULE:
                project_name = settings.SETTINGS_MODULE.split('.')[0]
                try:
                    url = reverse(project_name + '.' + request.resolver_match.view_name,
                          args=request.resolver_match.args, kwargs=request.resolver_match.kwargs,
                          current_app=context.current_app)
                except NoReverseMatch:
                    if self.asvar is None:                      
                        six.reraise(*exc_info)
            else:
                if self.asvar is None:
                    raise

        if self.asvar:
            context[self.asvar] = url
            return ''
        else:
            return url

@register.tag
def current_url(parser, token):
    bits = token.split_contents()
    bits = bits[1:]
    asvar = None
    if len(bits) >= 2 and bits[-2] == 'as':
        asvar = bits[-1]
        bits = bits[:-2]
    if len(bits):
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("Unexpected arguments to current_url tag")
    return CurrentURLNode(asvar)
```

There is no need to use the 'set_language' django view. There is no need to make a POST request to change the active language. With only html archors linking all your internationalized content together, it's better for SEO.