# Implementing Django language selection form as buttons

Tags: python, django, forms, internationalization

I would like to implement the django language selection as a series of buttons, rather than a dropdown select based form. I've tried to do this by adding `submit`, `formaction` and `value` attributes to the button, but it is not working correctly.

What is the correct way of implementing the the below input form into a series of buttons? Thanks!

**From the Django internationalization docs**:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
  <select name="language">
    {% for language in languages %}
      <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**My attempt with a button**:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

{% for language in languages %}
  <button type="submit" title="{{ language.code }}" formaction="{% url 'set_language' %}" value="{{ language.code }}">
    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }}) 
  </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As I cannot answer my own question yet, some more searching in seemingly unrelated questions led me to the answer to my own question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18393243/943773). I'll update this question with more examples when allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a method creating each language as its own hidden form with a submit button that can be [styled with css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp).

If you would like the active language to be styled differently, you could use a `django` if statement to change the css if it is the current language.

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

{% for language in languages %}
  <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="form_{{ language.code }}" style="display:inline!important;">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ language.code }}" />
  </form>
  <button class="lang-button" type="submit" form="form_{{ language.code }}" value="Submit">[{{ language.code }}]</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put all buttons in one form:

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
  {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
  {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
  {% for language in languages %}
    <button name="language" value="{{ language.code }}" type="submit">{{ language.code }}</button>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```