# How could I use Django i18n/setlang without form select and submit button?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-i18n

I need to render a language selector as an unordered list in Django such as:

```
<ul>
  ...
  <li><a href="???">EN</a></li>
  <li><a href="???">FR</a></li>
<ul>
```

I'm using Django `i18n/set_language` without `i18n_pattern` and it works very well if I use the form below, given in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view):

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I'd like to continue using `i18n/set_language`, but with the `<li>` structure, without the form `<select>` and the submit button.

Is it possible? How could I do this?

Answer (score 13):

As that link explains, the built-in set_language view is expecting a POST, which you can't do from a link (except by using Javascript).

But the next section, [Explicitly setting the active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language), gives you all the details you need to write your own view that can take the parameter from the URL. So:

```
def set_language_from_url(request, user_language):
    translation.activate(user_language)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
    return redirect(' ...somewhere... ')
```

and give it a URL:

```
url(r'/set_language/(?P<user_language>\w+)/$', set_language_from_url, name="set_language_from_url")
```

Now you can do:

```
<li><a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="en" %}">EN</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="fr" %}">FR</a></li>
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

I really didn't like the idea of having to do 2 clicks (one for selecting the language and another click to "Go" to submit it), so I found a work-around. It is still a form, but it works like a list:

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30779618/5802289), one can use buttons instead of links:

> ```
> <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
>     {% csrf_token %}
>     <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
>     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
>         {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
>         {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
>         {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
>         {% for language in languages %}
>             <li>
>                 <button type="submit"
>                         name="language"
>                         value="{{ language.code }}"
>                         class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
>                     {{ language.name_local }}
>                 </button>
>             </li>
>         {% endfor %}
>     </ul>
> </form>
> ```

Then, as per [Bootstrap Dropdown docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/):

> Historically dropdown menu contents had to be links, but that’s no
>   longer the case with v4. Now you can optionally use  elements
>   in your dropdowns instead of just s.

Merge both and tune it a bit with css to make it look like a list, and this is how it looks like for me:

[image: Language dropdown menu screenshot]

### css

```
.language-btn{
    background-color: #c9f0dd;
    border: 1px solid #c9f0dd;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #0C4B33;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.navbar-right{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    min-width: inherit;
}

.fake-btn{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    height: 12px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.no-margins{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.selected{
    color: #0C4B33;
}
```

### html

```
<div class="btn-group nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle language-btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    {% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}
    {{ lang.name_local }} ({{ lang.code }})
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
      <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
              {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
              {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
              {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
              {% for language in languages %}
                  <ul class="no-margins">
                      <button type="submit"
                              name="language"
                              value="{{ language.code }}"
                              class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %} dropdown-item fake-btn">
                          {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                      </button>
                  </ul>
              {% endfor %}
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to include this path as Django docs says:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#miscellaneous

`path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),`