# Django language selection from dropdown (links and images)

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n

I could use this code:

`mytemplate.html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <select name="language">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            <option value='it' {% if 'it' == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}> Italiano</option>
            <option value='en' {% if 'en' == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}> English</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

It works translating my page without changing the `url`.

But I don't like how it look, I prefer a dropdown menù (it look better in my toolbar, also I can add images). I tried many things until I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392405/issue-trying-to-change-language-from-django-template/18393243#18393243) this:

```
<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' 
    aria-expanded='false'>Lingua<span class='caret'></span></a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
    <li><a href="/it{{ request.get_full_path }}" class='language' lang='it'><img width='16' height='12' src="{% static 'icons/italian.png' %}" alt='Italiano' /> Italiano</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en{{ request.get_full_path }}" class='language' lang='en'><img width='16' height='12' src="{% static 'icons/english.png' %}" alt='English' /> English</a></li>
</ul>
```

but this add a prefix to my url (it/ or en/) and my url haven't prefix, so it gives page not found 404.

Is there a way to use the standard [django view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.set_language) with a dropdown menù?

Edit: here the django translation code, maybe it helps:

`Envs>myproject>Lib>site-packages>django>conf>urls>i18n.py`:

```
import warnings

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import LocaleRegexURLResolver
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning
from django.views.i18n import set_language


def i18n_patterns(prefix, *args):
    """
    Adds the language code prefix to every URL pattern within this
    function. This may only be used in the root URLconf, not in an included
    URLconf.
    """
    if isinstance(prefix, six.string_types):
        warnings.warn(
            "Calling i18n_patterns() with the `prefix` argument and with tuples "
            "instead of django.conf.urls.url() instances is deprecated and "
            "will no longer work in Django 1.10. Use a list of "
            "django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.",
            RemovedInDjango110Warning, stacklevel=2
        )
        pattern_list = patterns(prefix, *args)
    else:
        pattern_list = [prefix] + list(args)
    if not settings.USE_I18N:
        return pattern_list
    return [LocaleRegexURLResolver(pattern_list)]


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^setlang/$', set_language, name='set_language'),
]
```

`Envs>myproject>Lib>site-packages>django>views>i18n.py`:

```
import gettext as gettext_module
import importlib
import json
import os

from django import http
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import translate_url
from django.template import Context, Engine
from django.utils import six
from django.utils._os import upath
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.formats import get_format, get_format_modules
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
from django.utils.translation import (
    LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY, check_for_language, get_language, to_locale,
)

DEFAULT_PACKAGES = ['django.conf']
LANGUAGE_QUERY_PARAMETER = 'language'


def set_language(request):
    """
    Redirect to a given url while setting the chosen language in the
    session or cookie. The url and the language code need to be
    specified in the request parameters.

    Since this view changes how the user will see the rest of the site, it must
    only be accessed as a POST request. If called as a GET request, it will
    redirect to the page in the request (the 'next' parameter) without changing
    any state.
    """
    next = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next'))
    if not is_safe_url(url=next, host=request.get_host()):
        next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        if not is_safe_url(url=next, host=request.get_host()):
            next = '/'
    response = http.HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lang_code = request.POST.get(LANGUAGE_QUERY_PARAMETER)
        if lang_code and check_for_language(lang_code):
            next_trans = translate_url(next, lang_code)
            if next_trans != next:
                response = http.HttpResponseRedirect(next_trans)
            if hasattr(request, 'session'):
                request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = lang_code
            else:
                response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang_code,
                                    max_age=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE,
                                    path=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH,
                                    domain=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
    return response


def get_formats():
    """
    Returns all formats strings required for i18n to work
    """
    FORMAT_SETTINGS = (
        'DATE_FORMAT', 'DATETIME_FORMAT', 'TIME_FORMAT',
        'YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT', 'MONTH_DAY_FORMAT', 'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT',
        'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT', 'FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK', 'DECIMAL_SEPARATOR',
        'THOUSAND_SEPARATOR', 'NUMBER_GROUPING',
        'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS', 'TIME_INPUT_FORMATS', 'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'
    )
    result = {}
    for module in [settings] + get_format_modules(reverse=True):
        for attr in FORMAT_SETTINGS:
            result[attr] = get_format(attr)
    formats = {}
    for k, v in result.items():
        if isinstance(v, (six.string_types, int)):
            formats[k] = smart_text(v)
        elif isinstance(v, (tuple, list)):
            formats[k] = [smart_text(value) for value in v]
    return formats


js_catalog_template = r"""
{% autoescape off %}
(function(globals) {

  var django = globals.django || (globals.django = {});

  {% if plural %}
  django.pluralidx = function(n) {
    var v={{ plural }};
    if (typeof(v) == 'boolean') {
      return v ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
      return v;
    }
  };
  {% else %}
  django.pluralidx = function(count) { return (count == 1) ? 0 : 1; };
  {% endif %}

  /* gettext library */

  django.catalog = django.catalog || {};
  {% if catalog_str %}
  var newcatalog = {{ catalog_str }};
  for (var key in newcatalog) {
    django.catalog[key] = newcatalog[key];
  }
  {% endif %}

  if (!django.jsi18n_initialized) {
    django.gettext = function(msgid) {
      var value = django.catalog[msgid];
      if (typeof(value) == 'undefined') {
        return msgid;
      } else {
        return (typeof(value) == 'string') ? value : value[0];
      }
    };

    django.ngettext = function(singular, plural, count) {
      var value = django.catalog[singular];
      if (typeof(value) == 'undefined') {
        return (count == 1) ? singular : plural;
      } else {
        return value[django.pluralidx(count)];
      }
    };

    django.gettext_noop = function(msgid) { return msgid; };

    django.pgettext = function(context, msgid) {
      var value = django.gettext(context + '\x04' + msgid);
      if (value.indexOf('\x04') != -1) {
        value = msgid;
      }
      return value;
    };

    django.npgettext = function(context, singular, plural, count) {
      var value = django.ngettext(context + '\x04' + singular, context + '\x04' + plural, count);
      if (value.indexOf('\x04') != -1) {
        value = django.ngettext(singular, plural, count);
      }
      return value;
    };

    django.interpolate = function(fmt, obj, named) {
      if (named) {
        return fmt.replace(/%\(\w+\)s/g, function(match){return String(obj[match.slice(2,-2)])});
      } else {
        return fmt.replace(/%s/g, function(match){return String(obj.shift())});
      }
    };


    /* formatting library */

    django.formats = {{ formats_str }};

    django.get_format = function(format_type) {
      var value = django.formats[format_type];
      if (typeof(value) == 'undefined') {
        return format_type;
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    };

    /* add to global namespace */
    globals.pluralidx = django.pluralidx;
    globals.gettext = django.gettext;
    globals.ngettext = django.ngettext;
    globals.gettext_noop = django.gettext_noop;
    globals.pgettext = django.pgettext;
    globals.npgettext = django.npgettext;
    globals.interpolate = django.interpolate;
    globals.get_format = django.get_format;

    django.jsi18n_initialized = true;
  }

}(this));
{% endautoescape %}
"""


def render_javascript_catalog(catalog=None, plural=None):
    template = Engine().from_string(js_catalog_template)
    indent = lambda s: s.replace('\n', '\n  ')
    context = Context({
        'catalog_str': indent(json.dumps(
            catalog, sort_keys=True, indent=2)) if catalog else None,
        'formats_str': indent(json.dumps(
            get_formats(), sort_keys=True, indent=2)),
        'plural': plural,
    })

    return http.HttpResponse(template.render(context), 'text/javascript')


def get_javascript_catalog(locale, domain, packages):
    default_locale = to_locale(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    app_configs = apps.get_app_configs()
    allowable_packages = set(app_config.name for app_config in app_configs)
    allowable_packages.update(DEFAULT_PACKAGES)
    packages = [p for p in packages if p in allowable_packages]
    t = {}
    paths = []
    en_selected = locale.startswith('en')
    en_catalog_missing = True
    # paths of requested packages
    for package in packages:
        p = importlib.import_module(package)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(upath(p.__file__)), 'locale')
        paths.append(path)
    # add the filesystem paths listed in the LOCALE_PATHS setting
    paths.extend(reversed(settings.LOCALE_PATHS))
    # first load all english languages files for defaults
    for path in paths:
        try:
            catalog = gettext_module.translation(domain, path, ['en'])
            t.update(catalog._catalog)
        except IOError:
            pass
        else:
            # 'en' is the selected language and at least one of the packages
            # listed in `packages` has an 'en' catalog
            if en_selected:
                en_catalog_missing = False
    # next load the settings.LANGUAGE_CODE translations if it isn't english
    if default_locale != 'en':
        for path in paths:
            try:
                catalog = gettext_module.translation(domain, path, [default_locale])
            except IOError:
                catalog = None
            if catalog is not None:
                t.update(catalog._catalog)
    # last load the currently selected language, if it isn't identical to the default.
    if locale != default_locale:
        # If the currently selected language is English but it doesn't have a
        # translation catalog (presumably due to being the language translated
        # from) then a wrong language catalog might have been loaded in the
        # previous step. It needs to be discarded.
        if en_selected and en_catalog_missing:
            t = {}
        else:
            locale_t = {}
            for path in paths:
                try:
                    catalog = gettext_module.translation(domain, path, [locale])
                except IOError:
                    catalog = None
                if catalog is not None:
                    locale_t.update(catalog._catalog)
            if locale_t:
                t = locale_t
    plural = None
    if '' in t:
        for l in t[''].split('\n'):
            if l.startswith('Plural-Forms:'):
                plural = l.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
    if plural is not None:
        # this should actually be a compiled function of a typical plural-form:
        # Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 :
        #               n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;
        plural = [el.strip() for el in plural.split(';') if el.strip().startswith('plural=')][0].split('=', 1)[1]

    pdict = {}
    maxcnts = {}
    catalog = {}
    for k, v in t.items():
        if k == '':
            continue
        if isinstance(k, six.string_types):
            catalog[k] = v
        elif isinstance(k, tuple):
            msgid = k[0]
            cnt = k[1]
            maxcnts[msgid] = max(cnt, maxcnts.get(msgid, 0))
            pdict.setdefault(msgid, {})[cnt] = v
        else:
            raise TypeError(k)
    for k, v in pdict.items():
        catalog[k] = [v.get(i, '') for i in range(maxcnts[msgid] + 1)]

    return catalog, plural

...
```

Comment: How do you expect the urls for each language to work? What would be your urls.py configuration? And views.py?

Comment: I'm following the docs (link above) so I'm using the build-in django traslation set and so my url is: url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')), my view is: django.views.i18n.set_language(). The first template is working: I select the language, click the 'go' button (boring) and the page is traslated without changes in url (off course I have set django.po file, locale_path etc). Probabily the problem is in the href, maybe I have to call somehow {% url 'set_language' %} but I'm not expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution, but please tell me if there is something wrong

`mytemplate.html`:

```
  <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' 
    aria-expanded='false'>{% trans "Lingua" %}<span class='caret'></span></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
    <li>
      <form name="languageIt" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="it" />
        <a href="javascript:document.languageIt.submit()"><img width='16' height='12' src="{% static 'icons/italian.png' %}" alt='it' /> Italiano</a>
      </form>                      
    </li>
    <li>
      <form name="languageEn" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="en" />
        <a href="javascript:document.languageEn.submit()"><img width='16' height='12' src="{% static 'icons/english.png' %}" alt='en' /> English</a>
      </form> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```