# python Url translation on django authentication

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

this is a url after sign out
localhost:8000/en/Users/sign-in/?next=/en/Users/

but if i change language preference and log in language doesn't change because when i change language preference url becomes

localhost:8000/ru/Users/sign-in/?next=/en/Users/

after login
localhost:8000/en/Users/

then after pressing log out it changes
localhost:8000/ru/Users/sign-in/?next=/ru/Users/

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

]

```
urlpatterns += solid_i18n_patterns(
url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^Users/sign-in/$', auth_views.login,
    {'template_name': 'Users/sign_in.html'},
    name='Users-sign-in'),
url(r'^Users/sign-out/$', auth_views.logout,
{'next_page': '/'},
name='Users-sign-out'),
url(r'^Users/$', views.Users_home, name= 'Users-home'),
```

)

update
used these already discussed topic solution. didnt work

[Issue trying to change language from Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392405/issue-trying-to-change-language-from-django-template/18393243#18393243)

[Django: i18n - change language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489601/django-i18n-change-language)

Comment: It is building URL at the time of pressing logout. so first change language preference and go to log out. it will work expected

Comment: log out is working as expected. when i change language from language bar. it doesnt update the language code after next localhost:8000/ru/Users/sign-in/?next=/en/Users/

Answer (score 0):

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL does the trick