# How to create i18n switcher for Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-i18n, i18n-switcher

I could create **i18n switcher** for **English** and **French** below in Django following [The set_language redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) and this is [how I set up translation(English and French) in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418). *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("my_app1/", include('my_app1.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += [
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n"))
]
```

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

{% translate "Hello" %} {% trans "World" %}
```

Then, I can switch **French** to **English** as shown below:

[image]

And, I can switch **English** to **French** as shown below:

[image]

But, I don't know how to create it for Django Admin.

So, how can I create **i18n switcher** for Django Admin?

Answer (score 0):

First, set up translation(**English** and **French**) following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418).

Then, you need to create `custom_admin.css` in `core/static/core/admin/css/` and prepare `usa_flag.png` and `france_flag.png` in `core/static/core/admin/images/` and create `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `i18n_switcher.py` in `core/templatetags/` and copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-static
 |  |  └-core
 |  |     └-admin
 |  |        |-css
 |  |        |  └-custom_admin.css # Here
 |  |        └-images
 |  |           |-usa_flag.png # Here
 |  |           └-france_flag.png # Here
 |  └-templatetags
 |     |-__init__.py # Here
 |     └-i18n_switcher.py # Here
 |-my_app1
 |  |-views.py
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-models.py
 |  |_admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 |-templates
 |  |-admin
 |  |  └-base.html # Here
 |  └-index.html
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo
```

And, put the code below to `custom_admin.css`:

```css
/* "core/static/core/admin/css/custom_admin.css" */ 

img.i18n_flag {
    width: 16px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

And, put the code below to `i18n_switcher.py`:

```py
# "core/templatetags/i18n_switcher.py"

from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def switch_i18n(full_path, prefix_lang):
    lang_codes = [list[0] for list in settings.LANGUAGES]

    if prefix_lang not in lang_codes:
        raise Exception('%s is not a supported language code' % prefix_lang)
 
    parts = full_path.split('/')

    parts[1] = prefix_lang
    
    return '/'.join(parts)
```

And, add `<link ... 'core/admin/css/custom_admin.css' %}"/>` after `<link ... "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">` and add `<a ...><img ... 'core/admin/images/usa_flag.png' %}"/></a> /` and `<a ...><img ... 'core/admin/images/france_flag.png' %}"/></a> /` after `{% block userlinks %}` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/admin/base.html" %}

...
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'core/admin/css/custom_admin.css' %}"/>
... 
<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
    ...
    <div id="header">
        ...    
        <div id="user-tools">
            ....
            {% block userlinks %}
                {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %} 
                <a href="{% switch_i18n request.get_full_path 'en' %}">
                    <img class="i18n_flag" src="{% static 'core/admin/images/usa_flag.png' %}"/>
                </a> /
                {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %} 
                <a href="{% switch_i18n request.get_full_path 'fr' %}">
                    <img class="i18n_flag" src="{% static 'core/admin/images/france_flag.png' %}"/>
                </a> /
                ...
```

Now, you can switch **French** to **English** by clicking on **USA flag** as shown below:

[image]

And, you can switch **English** to **French** by clicking on **France flag** as shown below:

[image]

Actually, you can add your code `<form ...></form>` after `<div id="branding">...</div>` as shown below to create **i18n switcher** for English and French in Django Admin:

```
{% "templates/admin/base.html" %}

...
<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
    ...
    <div id="header">
        <div id="branding">
        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
        <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
            <select name="language">
                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                {% for language in languages %}
                    <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
```

Then, you can switch **French** to **English** as shown below:

[image]

And, you can switch **English** to **French** as shown below:

[image]

But, I prefer the 1st solution.